# Android: ScrollView Not Scrolling

Tags: android

I am making an app where you put text in list items and the app chooses text from a list item. I made the XML but problem is you can't scroll. It tries to scroll in the EditText you are in. 
Could anyone help?

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter List Name here"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:paddingTop="50px"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:paddingTop="20px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="1."
        android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

            <EditText
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="Enter List Item 1"
            android:id="@+id/listitem1"
            android:paddingTop="50px"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="2."
                android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="Enter List Item 2"
                android:id="@+id/listitem2"
                android:paddingTop="50px"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="3."
                android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="Enter List Item 3"
                android:id="@+id/listitem3"
                android:paddingTop="50px"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="2."
                android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="Enter List Item 2"
                android:id="@+id/listitem2"
                android:paddingTop="50px"/>

    </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="4."
            android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="Enter List Item 4"
            android:id="@+id/listitem4"
            android:paddingTop="50px"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-17dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="2."
                android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="Enter List Item 5"
                android:id="@+id/listitem5"
                android:paddingTop="50px"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-17dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="3."
                android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="Enter List Item 6"
                android:id="@+id/listitem6"
                android:paddingTop="50px"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/bSave"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll..... You have several LinearLayouts in yours
 From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all your LinearLayouts in a ScrollView yourself. A ScrollView can only host one child so you actually have to wrap all your Layouts in another LinearLayout

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android_layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android_layout_height="match_parent">

<!--ALL YOUR STUFF IN HERE-->

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Something like  this